# I received this error ORA-00984 column not allowed here

Tags: oracle, compiler-errors

```
Create table emo(
Emo_id number(10) NOT NULL,
Name varchar2(100) NOT NULL,
Band var char2(2),
Emp_type varchar2(5) DEFAULT "FTE" NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Double-quotes are for **object identifier (table, column) names"**. Use single-quotes for string literals.

Comment: You have a single space in the wrong place: `Band var char2(2)` That should be: `Band varchar2(2)`

Comment: And as an aside, I'd suggest you make your column  names a bit more descriptive and less likely to collide with reserved words.  I use the standard that all column names are in the form of 'adjective_noun', and with some standardized abbreviations.  So instead of NAME I'd have EMP_NAME.  Or maybe EMP_FIRST_NAME, if that was more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
CREATE TABLE emo
(
   Emo_id    NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
   Name      VARCHAR2 (100) NOT NULL,
   Band      VARCHAR2 (2),
   Emp_type  VARCHAR2 (5) DEFAULT 'FTE' NOT NULL
);
```

So:

- not double but single quotes for column's default value
- not `var char2` but `varchar2`